# My Watchkit App is running an old storyboard that I have removed and deleted - what is happening?

Tags: storyboard, watchkit

I created a Watchkit App and created a storyboard called TWWatch.storyboard.

I completely removed the Watchkit App and Extension from my main App. in xCode.

I deleted the 2 targets for Watchkit App and Extension, in xCode.

I deleted the files and directories related to these from my hard drive and even emptied my Trash.

This storyboard no longer exists on my Mac.

I add a new Watchkit Target to my App.

I creates the default files and the default storyboard interface.storyboard.

I run the Watchkit App and lo and behold it displays the TWWatch.storyboard.

How is this possible - I feel like I am going mad.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went mad yesterday, too. I got the same issue - although I had created a new storyboard, it always showed the old one.

For me, just cmd + shift + K (Clean) worked. If it doesn't work for you, please leave a comment to my answer.